# Get custom attribute in CatalogInventory module

Tags: magento2, attributes

So far I have created custom attribute `my_custom_attribute` and I want to pass this attribute inside `Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/StockStateProvider.php` and call it like `$stockItem->getIsInStock()` but I want to get it like `$stockItem-getMyAttribute()`. Can someone explain me how to do it? Can't really understand how to set this data to get my attribute there

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To get your custom attribute value in `Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/StockStateProvider.php` model file you just need to do following steps.

1. Override Model file in custom module `Mee/CustomModule/Model/StockStateProvider.php` as mentioned in below link https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/
2. Include your function in the above overdid model file as

   `protected function getMyAttribute()
   {
       $product = $this->productFactory->create();
       return $product->getMyAttribute();
   }`
3. Run magento upgrade and deployment commands from your root directory.

now you can call `$stockItem-getMyAttribute()` in your file